# Uploading to S3 with Laravel 4 - Getting Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to upload images to my S3 bucket. I am using the "Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider" and I getting this error:

```
Guzzle \ Common \ Exception \ InvalidArgumentException
Unknown type passed to configuration loader: integer
```

I am following the docs. Here is the contents of the aws.php file:

```
return array(
  'key'    => '1AW0WZEW23...',
  'secret' => 'SSz0H69JEAselT...',
  'region' => Aws\Common\Enum\Region::US_WEST_2,
);
```

I added this in my controller:

```
$path = public_path('public') . '/uploads/profile_pics/';
$ext = Input::file('profile_pic')->getClientOriginalName();
$fn = $randfile . '_' . $ext;

$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
  'Bucket'     => 'nestr_profile_pics',
  'Key'        => $fn,
  'SourceFile' => $path,
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting this error b/c your aws.php config file isn't starting with php script tags

```
<?php
return array(
'key'    => '1AW0WZEW23...',
'secret' => 'SSz0H69JEAselT...',
'region' => Aws\Common\Enum\Region::US_WEST_2,
);
```

and therefore the config array isn't getting passed into Guzzle.

Comment: I got it...what an oversight on the tags...oops. works great now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CDN Assets Manager Package for Laravel, That supports Amazon S3 by default.

**https://github.com/Vinelab/cdn**

#### Install it Via Composer:

```
    {
    "require": {
        "vinelab/cdn": "*"
    }
```

#### Add your CDN Credentials:

```
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '',
            'secret'    => '',
        ],

        'buckets' => [
            'bucket-name-here' => '*',
        ]
```

#### Specify directories, extensions, files and patterns to be uploaded

```
'include'    => [
    'directories'   => ['public/dist'],
    'extensions'    => ['.js', '.css', '.yxz'],
    'patterns'      => ['**/*.coffee'],
],
```

#### Also specify what to be ignored

```
'exclude'    => [
    'directories'   => ['public/uploads'],
    'files'         => [''],
    'extensions'    => ['.TODO', '.txt'],
    'patterns'      => ['src/*', '.idea/*'],
    'hidden'        => true, // ignore hidden files
],
```

---

#### USAGE:

1. Run this artisan command to push your assets to the CDN.

   **php artisan cdn:push**
2. Use it as follow in your Views or anywhere else in your code:

   **{{ Cdn::asset('public/assets/js/script.js') }}**

   **{{ Cdn::asset('public/assets/css/main.css') }}**